# Check if dictionaries match in a list of dicts & if they do, add value True or False

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I would like to compare two list of dictionaries, if the dictionary matches then add a key/value True to the second list of dictionaries; and if they don't match add a key/value False to the second list of dictionaries.

Current code:

```
list_dict1 = [{'animal': 'Dog', 'age': '3'}, {'animal':'Horse', 'age': '6'}]
list_dict2 = [{'animal': 'Dog', 'age': '3'}, {'animal':'Horse', 'age': '8'}]

for d1 in list_dict1:
    for d2 in list_dict2:
        if d1 == d2:
            d2['match'] = True
        else:
            d2['match'] = False
```

Current output:

```
list_dict2 = [{'animal': 'Dog', 'age': '3', 'match': False},
 {'animal': 'Horse', 'age': '8', 'match': False}]
```

Desired output:

```
list_dict2 = [{'animal': 'Dog', 'age': '3', 'match': True},
 {'animal': 'Horse', 'age': '8', 'match': False}]
```

I'm assuming that the reason why this does not work, is because at each iteration the `list_dict2` changes, meaning that there is no match further down the loops because I am adding a new value. Any ideas how I can proceed ?

Comment: I don't actually understand what you are trying to do? Isn't your code just checking the last dict in list1 with each dict in list2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your solution is that you override the results again.

I would just go over the second list and check if each item is in the first list like this:

```
for d1 in list_dict2:
    if d1 in list_dict1:
        d1['match'] = True
    else:
        d1['match'] = False

print(list_dict2)
```

Output:

```
[{'animal': 'Dog', 'age': '3', 'match': True},
 {'animal': 'Horse', 'age': '8', 'match': False}]
```

Comment: for some reason, I thought that I had to iterate per each list of dict..